# What does -> mean in PDO PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm a complete beginner in learning PDO for PHP and I actually haven't learned MySQL or MySQLi yet.

(Please take a look at the code below) I'm trying to make sense of what this " -> " arrow means and I couldn't find an answer anywhere else. Is the arrow semantically equivalent to the action word "perform" in every day english?

E.G for the codes below, $stmt (perform) -> closeCursor();

Code:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array($title,$entry));
$stmt->closeCursor();
```

Thank you.

Comment: Method call of the specific object http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.inheritance.php

Comment: before learning about databases, you should learn basic language syntax

Comment: In your code, $db is an instance of the database connection. With PDO you can use methods like prepare, execute, and others. Take a look on good tutorial about PDO.

Comment: [Check this](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php).

Comment: It means that PHP decided to be difficult and NOT use dot notation

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The arrow is part of PHP's **object syntax**, it's saying:

```
$object->method();
```

In English is:

> Run **method** on **object**

It's also used for accessing properties.

As **PDO** is a class in PHP and variables like `$db` are instances of that class, you're able to make use of the methods and properties in those instances.

Check out [PHP's object docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php) for more info on the subject, and if you're new to **Object Oriented programming** then you'll need to research the subject.

Comment: I guess you would recommend that I search up Object Oriented Programming and learn the intro to that and then try to make sense of PDO?

Comment: Yep, PDO is based on the principals of OOP, and it's an excellent paradigm to understand for modern programming.

Answer (score 0):

That is php's object notation equivilent to `.` in Java and Javascript. Basically it's used to access a method or property of an object.

See the [Objects and Classes documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php).